# How do I stop threads stalling on pthread_join?

Tags: c, queue, pthreads, mutex, pthread-join

I've got a project where I'm adding jobs to a queue and I have multiple threads taking jobs, and calculating their own independent results.

My program handles the SIGINT signal and I'm attempting to join the threads to add up the results, print to screen, and then exit. My problem is is that the threads either seem to stop functioning when I send the signal, or they're getting blocked on the mutex_lock. Here are the important parts of my program so as to be concise.

**main.c**

```
//the thread pool has a queue of jobs inside
//called jobs (which is a struct)
struct thread_pool * pool;

void signal_handler(int signo) {
    pool->jobs->running = 0; //stop the thread pool
    pthread_cond_broadcast(pool->jobs->cond);

    for (i = 0; i < tpool->thread_count; i++) {
        pthread_join(tpool->threads[i], retval);
        //do stuff with retval
    }

    //print results then exit
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);
    //set up threadpool and jobpool
    //start threads (they all run the workerThread function)
    while (1) {
        //send jobs to the job pool
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**thread_stuff.c**

```
void add_job(struct jobs * j) {
    if (j->running) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(j->mutex);
        //add job to queue and update count and empty
        pthread_cond_signal(j->cond);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(j->mutex);
    }
}

struct job * get_job(struct jobs * j) {

    pthread_mutex_lock(j->mutex);

    while (j->running && j->empty)
        pthread_cond_wait(j->cond, j->mutex);

    if (!j->running || j->empty) return NULL;

    //get the next job from the queue
    //unlock mutex and send a signal to other threads
    //waiting on the condition
    pthread_cond_signal(j->cond);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(j->mutex);
    //return new job
}

void * workerThread(void * arg) {
    struct jobs * j = (struct jobs *) arg;
    int results = 0;
    while (j->running) {
        //get next job and process results
    }
    return results;
}
```

Thanks for your help, this is giving me a real headache!

Comment: If you read [this POSIX signal concept reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_04), you will see at the end of section 2.4.3 a list of functions that are *async-safe* and therefore may be safely used from a signal handler. If you look through that list you will see that [`pthread_join](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_join.html) is *not* listed. That means you should not call it in a signal handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not call `pthread_cond_wait` or `pthread_join` from a signal handler which handles asynchronously generated signals such as `SIGINT`.  Instead, you should block `SIGINT` for all threads, spawn a dedicated thread, and call `sigwait` there.  This means that you detect the arrival of the `SIGINT` signal outside of a signal handler context, so that you are not restricted to [async-signal-safe functions](http://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html).  You also avoid the risk of self-deadlock in case the signal is delivered to one of the worker threads.

At this point, you just need to shut down your work queue/thread pool in an orderly manner.  Depending on the details, your existing approach with the `running` flag might even work unchanged.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I also had a problem then when I was exiting the get_job function due to shutdown I wasn't unlocking the mutex :') So what is the reason that pthread_join is not an async-signal-safe function?

Comment: Very few functions are async-signal-safe.  `pthread_join` needs to deallocate resources, and functions which manipulate the heap are never async-signal-safe because POSIX does not require an async-signal-safe memory allocator.